# Java 8 Filter list based on condition from the part of the list

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects N, where N is

```
N
|--- type (1,2,3)
|--- A (applicable if type 1)
|--- B (applicable if type 2)
|--- C (applicable if type 3)
|--- List<Integer> p
```

Now, the result I want is filtered version of List such that:

```
create a list List<Integer> l
```

Do this first:

```
if(type == 1) && (A > some_value):
  Add all elements of p to l
  select this N
```

Later once L is formed:

```
if(type != 1)
  if(l contains any element from p):
    select this N
```

How to achieve this using streams in one step?

I can filter and create a list "l" first and then use that list to filter.

```
l = stream.filter(a -> a.type == 1 && a.A > some_value).collect(..)
```

Then, use l to filter further.

But is there a better and precise way?

Comment: It is possible that your data structure is not suitable for the operation you need to execute. Is this data structure from a 3rd party or is it your own. It might be best if you can explain your intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if(type == 1) && (A > some_value):
>   Add all elements of p to l
>   select this N
> ```

Don't know what "select this N" means here, since you're selecting `p` values, so I'm ignoring that line.

```
Set<Integer> set = listOfN.stream()
    .filter(n -> n.type == 1 && n.A > some_value)
    .flatMap(n -> n.p.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

For better performance of the next step ([`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)), the result was changes from `List` to `Set`.

> ```
> if(type != 1)
>   if(l contains any element from p):
>     select this N
> ```

```
List<N> result = listOfN.stream()
    .filter(n -> n.type != 1 && n.p.stream().anyMatch(set::contains))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing so will get me only objects where type != 1, right?. What I want is if type 1, then check n.A > some_value, if type = 2 or 3, <follow other logic>. Sorry if this is not clearly mentioned in question.

Comment: Also, is it possible to combine both the steps?

Comment: @sakura You enhance the `filter` in the 2nd block to also include type 1's. --- It *could* be done in a single statement, but that would hurt performance, a lot!